# How to center text inside a div element?

Tags: html, css

How to center the text inside the div? I have the following css code: Should I use line-height property to center the text?

```
.activebox {
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 16px;
/*line-height: 20px;*/
background-color: #47DA91;
}

.triangle-left {
display: inline;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid #47DA91;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
float: left;
}

.activebox p {
color: white;
 }
```

and also the html code:

```
<div class="triangle-left"></div>
<div class="activebox"><p>Active</p></div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2JYZ/) example

Thank you.

Comment: use `text-align:center;` property in css. Also in your fiddle, there is another closing `</div>` tag, why it is there?

Comment: @VedantTerkar No no no ! `<center>` is deprecated as of HTML5 and should NOT be used.

Comment: @plywoods if you are talking about single line text; then you are allow to use `line-height` property.

Comment: Hi @plywoods. I don't think it's worth of me doing that but can you fix your title? iside -> inside. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: table-cell` to the `<p>` tag itself, similar to this:

```
.activebox p{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

In addition, either removed the `line-height: 22px` style from the `.activebox` as it off-sets the text vertically or only set it to the max height of the triangle which is `line-height: 16px`, then it will still look perfect.

```
.activebox {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    /*line-height: 22px;*/
    line-height: 16px; /* set to 16px or remove all together*/
    background-color: #47DA91;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YY9L5/) - Using `display: table-cell`

---

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YY9L5/1/ i changed the div height and width it dosent work.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However, It ihas strange behaviour when I change the font-size and change the page scale.

Comment: @plywoods: If you are designing a static site the font-size or height never changes and is only set at design time where you also adjust the rest of the CSS as needed. However, if you are working on a responsive site you might want to look at setting the base font size to an em (or rem as required) value instead. You could then use % in line-height, height and other font-sizes settings. Changing them per display breakpoint as needed. That should then just flow together....I believe.

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer: You should propably ask this in a new question if you have a requirement other than OP's. However, if you must compensate for bigger arrows you can always add `text-align: center; width: inherit` to the `.activebox p` styles. Also don't forget to add line-height to be the same as the height. See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvFaa/) - play around with it if you have other requirements, adding `border: 1px solid red` to the `.activebox p` style helps visualize the changes you make.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use the "display: table-cell" property.

[Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
.activebox {
   background-color: #47da91;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 16px;
   line-height: 0;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   top: -1px;
   width: 40px;
 }
.triangle-left {
   border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid #47da91;
   border-top: 8px solid transparent;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
 }
 .activebox p {
   color: white;
   font-size: 11px;
   position: relative;
   top: -3px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add following style for your `.activebox` class.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5L7b/)

---

#### References

- [CSS align-items Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)
- [CSS flex playground](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_align-items&preval=flex-start)

Answer (score -1):

text-align : center; in your css class

Comment: It seems the issue is vertical alignment not horizontal alignment.